# Error en conexión PostgreSQL con kotlin: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception

Tags: android, postgresql, kotlin

Estoy realizando un proyecto en android que se conecte a postgresql pero al lanzar el programa en el emulador me indica el error:

```
Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
```

He instalado diferentes versiones de JDBC pero no ha funcionado, de momento tengo instalada la versión más reciente de PostgreSQL en mi equipo de desarrollo Windows, que es la 15.3 y uso de JDBC 42.6.0

```
//implementación en graddle
implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0'


//clase conexión en kotlin
    class pgConnection {
    private val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=require"
    private val user = "postgres"
    private val password = ""
    private var conn: Connection? = null

    fun connect(): Connection {
        try {
            conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
        } catch (e: SQLException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Error al conectar a la base de datos: ${e.message}")
        }
        return conn!!
    }

    fun disconnect() {
        try {
            conn?.close()
        } catch (e: SQLException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Error al cerrar la conexión: ${e.message}")
        }
    }
}


//Intento de conexión
try {
            val pgConn = pgConnection()
            pgConn.connect()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Conexión exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            pgConn.disconnect()
        } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error en la conexión: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Log.i("shadowb", "Error= ${e.message}")
        }
```

Comment: Pero, ¿tienes una base de datos PostgreSQL en tu dispositivo Android?

Comment: No, es un servidor en windows y la app se ejecuta en el emulador de android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes comprender que, al ejecutar la aplicación en el emulador, se está ejecutando en una máquina virtual que ejecuta el sistema operativo Android y no directamente en tu máquina Windows.

Para esta máquina virtual, *localhost* apunta hacia su propia interface local de red (*loopback*).

La máquina Windows dónde se ejecuta esta máquina virtual es conocida como el anfitrión (*host* en inglés).

Por lo anteriormente dicho, la aplicación Android que se ejecuta dentro de este emulador, busca conectarse al puerto de PostgreSQL en el emulador mismo. Sabemos que allí no está corriendo el servidor de PostgreSQL, por lo tanto la conexión falla. Sabemos que este servidor está corriendo en el anfitrión.

Si quieres comunicarte con el anfitrión vía TCP/IP desde el emulador puedes utilizar la dirección especial `10.0.2.2`, que según la documentación del [espacio de red del emulador](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkaddresses) apunta a la interface *loopback* del host.

> | Network Address | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | 10.0.2.2 | Special alias to your host loopback interface (127.0.0.1 on your development machine) |

Así, tu código podría quedar como esto:

```
private val url = "jdbc:postgresql://10.0.2.2:5432/postgres?sslmode=require"
```

Te sugiero leer la documentación de redes referida, pues tiene más información de importancia.

Recuerda, por otro lado, que esto está bien para hacer pruebas en el emulador, pero una vez te prepares para hacer deploy a un dispositivo físico, tendrás que ajustar de nuevo la IP del servidor, pues esta dirección especial solamente existe dentro del emulador.

Comment: Puse la dirección 10.0.2.2:5432 para intentar localhost y me aparece: The connection attempt failed. También intenté hacerlo con una dirección a un servidor de postgres real y tambien sale el mismo error: The connection attempt failed

Comment: @Miguel El emulador no necesariamente tiene acceso a la LAN. Puedes intentar correr un web server en tu host windows y utilizar el navegador desde el emulador para probar la conexión. También puedes intentar navegar a algún otro servidor local o al internet, en función de ir diagnosticando la conectividad, ya que el problema no parece ser de postgre o de tu aplicación en particular.